# Occasional AWS Lambda timeouts, but otherwise sub-second execution

Tags: aws-lambda

We have an AWS Lambda written in Java that usually completes in about 200 ms. Occasionally, it times out after 5 seconds (our configured timeout value).

I understand that there is occasional added latency due to container setup (though, I'm not clear if that counts against your execution time). I added some debug logging, and it seems like the code just *runs slow*.

For example, a particularly noticeable log entry shows a call to `HttpClients.createDefault` usually takes less than 200 ms (based on the fact that the Lambda executes in less than 200 ms), but when the timeout happens, it takes around 2-3 seconds.

```
2017-09-14 16:31:28     DEBUG Helper:Creating HTTP Client
2017-09-14 16:31:31     DEBUG Helper:Executing request
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, it seems like any latency due to container initialization would have already happened. Am I wrong in assuming that code execution should not have dramatic differences in speed from one execution to the next? Or is this just something we should expect?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up new containers or replacing cold containers takes some time. Both account against your time. The time you see in the console is the time you are billed against.

I assume that Amazon doesn't charge for the provisioning of the container, but they will certainly hit the timer as soon as your runtime is started. You are likely to pay for the time during which the SDK/JDK gets initialized and loads it's classes. They are certainly not charging us for the starting of the operation system which hosts the containers.

Running a [simple Java Lambda](https://github.com/udoheld/aws-lambda-hello-log/blob/master/src/main/java/com/udoheld/aws/lambda/HelloLogSimple.java) two times shows the different times for new and reused instances. The first one is `374.58` ms and the second one is `0.89` ms. After that you see the billed duration of `400` and `100` ms. For the second one the container got reused. While you can try to keep your containers warm as already pointed out by @dashmug, AWS will occasionally recycle the containers and as load increases or decreases spawn new containers. The blogs [How long does AWS Lambda keep your idle functions around before a cold start?](https://read.acloud.guru/how-long-does-aws-lambda-keep-your-idle-functions-around-before-a-cold-start-bf715d3b810) and [How does language, memory and package size affect cold starts of AWS Lambda?](https://read.acloud.guru/does-coding-language-memory-or-package-size-affect-cold-starts-of-aws-lambda-a15e26d12c76) might be worth a look as well. If you include external libraries you times will increase. If you look at that blog you can see that for Java and smaller memory allocations can regularly exceed 2 - 4 seconds.

Looking at these times you should probably increase your timeout and not just have a look at the log provided by the application, but a look at the `START`, `END` and `REPORT` entries as well for an actual timeout event. Each running Lambda container instance seems to create its own log stream. Consider keeping your Lambdas warm if they aren't called that often.

```
05:57:20 START RequestId: bc2e7237-99da-11e7-919d-0bd21baa5a3d Version: $LATEST
05:57:20 Hello from Lambda com.udoheld.aws.lambda.HelloLogSimple. 
05:57:20 END RequestId: bc2e7237-99da-11e7-919d-0bd21baa5a3d
05:57:20 REPORT RequestId: bc2e7237-99da-11e7-919d-0bd21baa5a3d Duration: 374.58 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB
```

```
05:58:01 START RequestId: d534155b-99da-11e7-8898-2dcaeed855d3 Version: $LATEST
05:58:01 Hello from Lambda com.udoheld.aws.lambda.HelloLogSimple. 
05:58:01 END RequestId: d534155b-99da-11e7-8898-2dcaeed855d3
05:58:01 REPORT RequestId: d534155b-99da-11e7-8898-2dcaeed855d3 Duration: 0.89 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 44 MB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep your function always warm and see if it would make a difference.

If the timeout is really due to container warmup, then keeping it warm will greatly help reduce the frequency of these timeouts. You'd still get cold starts when you deploy changes but at least that's predictable.

https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-keep-your-lambda-functions-warm-9d7e1aa6e2f0

Answer (score 0):

For Java based applications the warm up period is more as you know it's jvm right. Better to use NodeJS or Python because the warm up period is less for them. If you are not in such a way to switch the tech stack simply keep the container warm by triggering it or increase the memory that will reduce the execution time as lambda cpu allocation is more for larger memory.